wordpress template not loading correspondig styles for menu
I have got Hero Agency wordpress template files. All looks good but jkit menu in theme header. It just looks unstyled and I can confirm that when I compare demo with template that I installed.
In demo theme, there is jkit-menu class added to ul tag, but at my side there is no such class. I might be missing something...
I tried to reload template files, to add header again but no luck.
I also tried to got to Jag Elementor kit to add header and customize it, but no luck.
wordpress is at 6.4.3.
I there a way to add menu styles or build menu. Or I am simply missed something during setup of theme files.

I managed to do it. it was stupid thing. I just installed one of the older free themes, twenty twenty-one and it fix thing that caused described behaviour. Now I was able to add, remove and edit menu as it should be.
